# PHP-dynamic condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Hi I wanna do something like this

```
<?php
$a = 0 ;
$b = 1 ;
$MyCondition = "$a < $b" ;

if ($MyCondition) // should be if($a < $b) !
    //DoSomething
?>
```

HOW to do it ?
Thank you !

Comment: @Gordon I tried to build a function which evaluates an expression in a string. I succeeded doing it using `eval()`

Comment: @MorCohen thanks for the update. Now that you know that you can use eval, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php and the answers in the linked dupe for better alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = 0 ;
$b = 1 ;
$MyCondition = $a < $b ;

if ($MyCondition) // 
    //DoSomething
?>
```

Comment: but I get $MyCondition as a string.. how could I deal with it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 2 ;
$b = 3 ;
$MyCondition = $a < $b ;

if ($MyCondition){
  echo "true";
}else{
  echo "false";
}
```

I don't see why though, when you can just use

```
if ($a < $b)
```